# Nlog ${event-context:item=xxxx} not passing null values

Tags: nlog

I am using event-context to log (using NLog method) some custom values to log table in the database. The custom value is a nullable integer - Id. In some cases where the Id is not yet generated I want to pass null value. But it turns out that instead of null event-context is passing zero to the procedure which is not acceptable in my case as there will be a foreign key on the Id column. The procedure is very simple - it just inserts the parameters into the log table. No additional logic in the procedure that would populate zero instead of null. Here's my code:

```
Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, "", "Pass my Id");
theEvent.Properties["Id"] = null;
log.Log(theEvent);
```

config:

```
commandText="execute dbo.saveLog @LogDateTime=@LogDateTime, 
                      @LogSource=@LogSource, 
                      @LogMessage=@LogMessage, 
                      @LogMessageType=@LogMessageType, 
                      @Id=@Id,
        <parameter name="@LogDateTime" layout="${date}" />
        <parameter name="@LogSource" layout="${callsite}" />
        <parameter name="@LogMessage" layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="@Id" layout="${event-context:item=Id}" />
```

When checking the log table there is 0 instead of null. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your `saveLog` stored procedure definition!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain if there is some other configuration for passing in nulls as NULL, but there is a straightforward workaround assuming your integers will never actually be zero (NLog seems to use zero by default):

```
<commandText>
  insert into LogApi ([TimeStamp],[Level],Logger, [Message], Id, Exception, StackTrace) values (@TimeStamp, @Level, @Logger, @Message, 
  CASE WHEN LEN(@Id) = 0 THEN NULL
  ELSE @Id
  END, 
  @Exception, @StackTrace);
</commandText>
```

Stolen from: http://blog.evizija.si/rest-web-api-logging-using-nlog/